# Вывод ассоциаций

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Привет ребята, собственно вопрос следующий не получается вывести связанные строки из другой таблицы, есть две модели Project и Todo две таблицы соответственно projects и todos, описываю модели:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
has_many :todos
end
```

и вторая

```
class Todo < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :project
end
```

задача вывести список проектов и задач закрепленных за ними, в контроллере пишу следующее

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @projects = Project.all
    @todos = Project.joins(:todos)
  end
end
```

затем во вьюхе пишу

```
<% @projects.each do |pr| %>
   <h2><%= pr.title %></h2>
       <% @todos.each do |to| %>
         <h4><%= to.todo %></h4>  
       <% end %>    
<% end %>
```

и получаю

[image: такой результат]

окей он предлагает мне указать метод todos у to где по идее у меня хранятся ассоциации для projects, но почему todos? если это название таблицы а не атрибут todo т.е название столбца где у меня записаны сами задания в таблице todos, ведь это срабатывает для project.title? и да если я делаю todos как он просит то получаю вот что [image: количество ассоциаций с данным проектом] подскажите пожалуйста чего я не понимаю? что делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы хотя бы в рельсовой консоли (`rails c`) проверяйте, что натворили.

```
@todos = Project.joins(:todos)
sample_todo = @todos.first
sample_todo.is_a?(Todo) # => false    # вот это поворот!
sample_todo.class       # => Project  # вот это поворо-о-от!
```

`Project.joins(:todos)` это список **проектов**, взятый из [*соединения* таблиц](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0)) моделей `Todo` и `Project`. В вашем случае это означает, что каждый `Project` в нём встретится столько раз, сколько у него есть `Todo`шек. То есть, да, проекты без `Todo` не попадут туда вообще.

А ларчик просто открывался. Вы ж объявили `has_many :todos` у `Project`, так что у каждого объекта класса `Project` теперь будет метод `todos`, который возвращает коллекцию **только его** `Todo`. А поскольку в `@todos` у вас объекты `Project`, у них у всех есть метод `todos`, который вам и предлагают.

Вам вообще не нужен `@todos`. Соответствующие проектам задачи можно тянуть прямо из объектов самих проектов:

```
Project.all.each do |project|
  project.todos.each do |todo|
    # что вы там хотели сделать с todo
  end
end
```

Но есть небольшая неприятность, если не принять дополнительных мер, Rails сделает по одному дополнительному запросу в `todos` на каждый проект, что довольно медленно. Этого можно избежать, если ["жадно загрузить" (см. руководства)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) их заранее для всех проектов [с помощью `includes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes):

```
Project.includes(:todos).all.each do |project|
  project.todos.each do |todo|
    # что вы там хотели сделать с todo
  end
end
```

И следите за тем, какие запросы выполняются в консоли в каждом из двух случаев.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо за столь подробный и развернутый ответ. Эта информация очень полезна для меня.

Comment: @newbie_rails вы можете поменять выбранный ответ, если хотите.

Answer (score 2):

Вам не нужно делать joins, вам нужно includes

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @projects = Project.includes(:todos).all
  end
end
```

И потом

```
<% @projects.each do |pr| %>
   <h2><%= pr.title %></h2>
   <% pr.todos.each do |to| %>
      <h4><%= to.todo %></h4>  
   <% end %>    
<% end %>
```

Comment: А вот еще небольшой вопрос. Когда мы в инстанс переменную записываем `Project.includes(:todos).all` то туда заносятся **все** объекты Project и к каждому объекту подтягиваются его ассоциации которые становятся методом у Project,  после чего можем обращаться к любым столбцам таблицы Projects а так же к Todos но только через метод у Projects. Плюс ко всему выводятся так же и пустые объекты Project. В контроллере метод `.all` не меняет абсолютно ничего что с ним что без него результат один, получается что в одной переменной просто свалка всего что можно и это все из за `has_many` ?

Comment: @newbie_rails ActiveRecord это god объект. Поэтому он делает все и имеет столько много методов. В вашем случае all действительно не нужен.